# Would it be possible to swap system restore points on different brands of computers?

Tags: windows, system-restore, deep-freeze

So I have a ThinkPad computer that I've installed a program called "Deep Freeze" which restores your computer to the "Frozen" state. I also have a Toshiba computer with no Deep Freeze on it.

My question is that would it be possible to creat a system restore point on my Toshiba and then replace the system volume information folder with the one on the ThinkPad so I could restore to a point with no Deep Freeze?

Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  Restore points are specific to the Windows instance they were created by.

Please note that they function different than back-ups, they only set some vital things back...

Comment: That's disappointing.

Comment: Windows installations are specific to the system's they're installed on too.  You *CAN* move a hard disk with windows to another system, but all bets are off it it'll work, work for long, or work properly.. seriously NOT recommended. (try cleaning up a few customer's systems who've tried this...)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to force a thawed deep freeze, try setting the system clock ahead at least 61 days in the bios.